# Java regex print word

Tags: java, regex

I want to print the word containing pattern `_fact`". For example in the below string want to print `agg_day_adv_campaign_demand_fact`.

```
String text =
  "FROM dt_dim AS d, "+
  "adj_dim AS adj " +
  "cam_dim AS cam, " +
  "agg_day_adv_campaign_demand_fact AS fact ";
```

Comment: You forgot, by mistake, to post your attempts :)

Comment: i believe you have pressed **Ask Question** button, not **Request Code** button

Comment: In order to get constructive answers you always have to show us your attempts to solve your problem by yourself together with the expected and received output/error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String text =
              "FROM dt_dim AS d, "+
              "adj_dim AS adj " +
              "cam_dim AS cam, " +
              "agg_day_adv_campaign_demand_fact AS fact ";

    Pattern FACT_PAT = Pattern.compile("(\\S+_fact)");
    Matcher m = FACT_PAT.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks JosefN. The above piece of code prints only the regex i.e _fact. But the requirement is to print the full word.

Comment: I've fixed it :), sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

regex \w*_fact will do it.
You can test this regex here (http://regexpal.com/)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text    =
                "FROM dt_dim AS d, "+
                        "adj_dim AS adj " +
                        "cam_dim AS cam, " +
                        "agg_day_adv_campaign_demand_fact AS fact ";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*_fact");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found the text " + matcher.group()+  "starting at " + matcher.start()
                    + " index and ending at index " + matcher.end());
            System.out.println(text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `split` the string into words and examine the words one by one to search for your pattern.